# Почему блок #wrapper не центрируются

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(164, 206, 169);
}

#wrapper {
  width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

figure {
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: e7e3d8;
}

figure img {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figcaption {
  /**/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Потому что он float: left

Comment: @AlexeyTen div'у указан flaot:left, а не #wrapper'у

Comment: А он что, не div что ли? Почитайте как работает CSS и в частности селекторы. Вообще глобальный селектор на div это нонсенс

Comment: И вообще для семантичности этот список логичнее бы сделать списком ul/li

Comment: Всё... Я понял о чем Вы)) Да, глупость дичайшую сделал)))

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Потому что он float: left | by [@AlexeyTen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948743/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-wrapper-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F#comment1580502_948743)

Вы указали для всех `div` свойство `float: left`, а ваш `#wrapper` является `div`ом.

Почитайте о [наследование](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/nasledovanie)

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(164, 206, 169);
}

#wrapper {
  width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper > div {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

figure {
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: e7e3d8;
}

figure img {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figcaption {
  /**/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="..." alt="Кот">
        <figcaption>Котяра</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```